# Multiplying and powering python float and pytorch integer

Tags: python, pytorch

Why does a python float multiplied by a torch.long gives a torch.float but powering a float by a torch.long gives a torch.long?

```
>>> a = 0.9
>>> b = torch.tensor(2, dtype=torch.long)

>>> foo = a * b
>>> print(foo, foo.dtype)
tensor(1.8000) torch.float32

>>> bar = a ** b 
>>> print(bar, bar.dtype)
tensor(0) torch.int64
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug, probably in the way pytorch binds `**` to `__rpow__` or `__pow__`.

E.g. if you tried `0.9 - torch.tensor(2)`, since 0.9 isn't a tensor, this gets interpreted as `torch.tensor(2).__rsub__(0.9)`, which works correctly. `**` behaves the same way, but `torch.tensor(2).__rpow__(0.9)` incorrectly returns `tensor(0)` with dtype int64.

In the meantime you can use `torch.tensor(0.9) ** torch.tensor(2)`.

Filed a bug:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/32436